# Factor Group size compared to G

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why is $G/H$ smaller than $G$ when $G$ is finite and $H \neq \{e\}$? Reading Chapter 9 of Gallian on Normal Subgroups and Factor Groups when this assertion is made referring to why factor groups are important.

Comment: The cosets of $H$ are disjoint, and each has the same number of elements as $H$. The elements of $G/H$ are just these cosets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may prove that 
$$
\left|G/H\right|=|G|/|H|
$$
so $|H|>1$ implies $|G/H|<|G|$.

Answer (score 1):

An argument similar to Brian's  ( it may be helpful to get different perspectives.) is that the cosets form a partition of the group. By a counting argument, there can be at most |G| cosets in $G/H$ (maybe assume normality of H to avoid well-definedness issues in G/H ).